# Eager loading (withCount), limit on how many models you can preload?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I'm having an issue where I have to display a table rendered client side, but the returned number of rows is about 2.5k entries. The model has a many-to-many relationship with a Sentence model through a bridging/pivot table with about 7k rows:

```
    public function sentences()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Sentence::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I'm trying to preload the Sentences via `$entries = Entry:::with('sentences')->get();` but this generates a query with 2.5k ids in it `where entry_sentence.entry_id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, ..., 2462, 2463, 2464)`.

This query generated runs in about 0.06s on my local machine. But it takes about 8 seconds to generate the collection, which I think is due to hydration? Without preloading its very fast, but then I run into n+1 issues looping over my rows.

**Am I forced into either "raw" DB::table() queries without Eloquent or pagination (and thus server side filtering ect.) ?** What is the reasonable limit on eager loaded relationships? I can't seem to find any advice on this anywhere. I'm using Datatables in frontend and their rule of thumb was doing AJAX until about 5k rows then you should consider going server side pagination instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the related query:

```php
$entries = Entry:::with('sentences' => function($query) {
    return $query->limit(5); // however many is useful
}])->get();
```